# Rotate camera with touch event

Tags: events, camera, three.js, touch

I am already able to rotate my camera around with mousedown/mousemove events.
Now Im trying to do the same on touch devices, but when I touch my document (trigger event), scene goes black.
In my code Im setting the position of camera.target and later in script I let the camera.lookat(camera.target).

here is touch-part of my code:

```
function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    isUserInteracting = true;
    onTouchX = event.clientX;
    onTouchY = event.clientY;
    onTouchLon = lon;
    onTouchLat = lat;
  }

  function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {
   if ( isUserInteracting ) {
    lon = ( onTouchX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + onTouchLon;
    lat = ( event.clientY - onTouchY ) * 0.1 + onTouchLat;
    needRender = true;
    }
  }
```

As I said I use same logic with mouse events so I dont know where I went wrong with touch.
I dont believe this question was asked before, so thx for any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps the [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) for `OrbitControls` will be helpful to you.

Comment: I used OrbitCobtrols in other project, worked fine but this is nto what Im looking for, because in Orbit Controls is camera obriting around a certain point in the scene .... and I need my camera to be still, and in the center of the scene looking around (like tank touret)

Comment: Solved through VirtualJoystick.js .... wokrs just fine enough